# Write multiline over an image

Tags: ios4, uiimage

`text1` is a very long string so, I want multiline support.
What do I have to do for this?

```
    int w = img.size.width;
    int h = img.size.height;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace= CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, w, h, 8, 4*w, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0,0, w, h), img.CGImage);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1);
    char* text = (char *)[text1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    CGContextSelectFont(context, "Arial", 18, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 255,255,255,1);

    //CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/4));;
    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, w/3 + 10, 5, text, strlen(text));
    CGImageRef imageMasked = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageMasked];
```

Comment: Don’t give up. I added a bounty. Maybe now someone will be able to answer it. :)

Comment: i didn't tagged it. Someone else edited my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using UIKit methods instead of CGContext methods to draw your text, you can just use [`drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006893-CH3-SW16) to draw the text, which will handle wrapping for you. Note that you can use [`UIGraphicsPushContext`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW2) and [`UIGraphicsPopContext`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW1) to go from your existing CGGraphicsRef to the UIKit context, and if you are targeting iOS earler than 4.0 you have to do the UIKit drawing on the main thread.

Comment: In drawInRect i can add color in the background, i want to set an image as background. I tried this, but it shows black background in my half of the image. Any help?

Comment: @SmritiYadav: The NSString method (added by UIKit) `drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:` doesn't draw any background, just the text.

Comment: i'm using this with context. I'm not able to implement this properly in my code. I want to write some text over my image. But it returns me CGSize and i'm not passing the text in parameter! Can you please provide me with some code showing me how to use this method, it would be really helpful.

Comment: [This Apple sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/WeatherMap/Listings/Classes_WeatherAnnotationView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009491-Classes_WeatherAnnotationView_m-DontLinkElementID_8) uses the very similar `drawInRect:withFont:` method.

Comment: Even in this example, they are using \n for next line. If we enter a long string without \n, some of my text gets clipped rather than going to next line. THanks @Anomie for your time. :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to support multiline.

Then you can always use this:

```
 CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia-Bold" size:18.0]
                   constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(240.0, 480.0) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

Assign the width and height (in `:CGSizeMake(240.0, 480.0)`), font type and size, and then assign this size for your `text1.frame`.

You will get your size according to your string and your text will be adjusted there.

Comment: I'm sorry if you misunderstood the question but i'm writing this text1 over an image where i want this to support multiline. so i can't set the frame of text1 as it is not user interface object. Do you have any other option?